# Updating a nested list object in the global environment from within a function in R

Tags: r, nested-lists

Here are the set of circumstances that have gotten me stuck:

### The Problem

I have written a function in R that will need to execute within a for loop with the goal of manually adjusting some values and then updating a large nested list in the global environment. I have 2 functions `more.points()` and `get.num.pts()` that ask for user input. These are part of a larger function `add.points()` which runs everything and will be wrapped in a for loop. Unfortunately, I cannot figure out how to update the nested list to the correct place in the list's hierarchy from within the function. I must do it from within the function in order to make sure I dont run lines of code in the for loop after the function because this will cause `readlines()` to fail and take the next line of code as user input. How do I update the hierarchical list object in the correct place from within the `add.points()` function? `assign()` does not appear to be up to the task, at least to my limited knowledge. Any help is greatly appreciated. I am making a pipeline for aligning an atlas to brain images so I can localize cells that fluoresce to their respective brain regions.

```
more.points <- function(){
  more.pts <- readline(prompt = "Do you need to add correspondence points to adjust the atlas registration? (y/n): ")
}

get.num.pts <- function(){
  num.pts <- readline(prompt = "How many additional points are required? (You will be able to add additional points later if you need to): ")
}

add.points <- function(){
  
  mo.pts  <- as.character(more.points());
  if(mo.pts == "y" || mo.pts == "Y" || mo.pts == "Yes" || mo.pts == "yes"){
    while(mo.pts == "y" || mo.pts == "Y" || mo.pts == "Yes" || mo.pts == "yes") {
      #ask for user input about number of new points to be created
      n.pts <- as.integer(get.num.pts());
      reg.fun.obj <- paste0(n.pts," updated!");
      print(reg.fun.obj)
      #do other stuff
#assign totally works here just fine because it isnt a hierarchical list being updated
      assign("reg.obj", reg.fun.obj, envir = .GlobalEnv);
      #Need to update the correct position in the list object hierarchy with new info.
      assign(i.data[[reference.df$i[[i]]]][[reference.df$j[[i]]]][[reference.df$k[[i]]]], reg.obj, envir = .GlobalEnv);
      #But this cannot take `i.data[[reference.df$i[[i]]]][[reference.df$j[[i]]]][[reference.df$k[[i]]]]` for the name argument. it must be a string.
      mo.pts = as.character(more.points())
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

### Reproducible example:

Here is an example of the global environment hierarchical list I need to update from an object within the `add.points()` function:

```
#Hierarchical List Object Example

#The image objects have more complexity in my real implementation i.e. image_1 is itself a list object with multiple attributes.
list.i <- c("channel1", "channel2", "channel3")
list.j <- c("m1", "m2", "m3")
list.k <- c("image_1", "image_2", "image_3")
  
k.tmp <- list()
j.tmp <- list()
i.data <- list()

for(i in seq_along(list.i)){
  for(j in seq_along(list.j)){
    for(k in seq_along(list.k)){
      k.tmp[[k]] <- list.k[[k]]
      names(k.tmp)[[k]] <- paste0("img", k)
    }
    j.tmp[[j]] <- k.tmp
    names(j.tmp)[[j]] <- paste0("m", j)
    k.tmp <- list()
  }
  i.data[[i]] <- j.tmp
  names(i.data)[[i]] <- paste0("channel", i)
  j.tmp <- list
}
remove(k.tmp,j.tmp)


#Additional example list I am using to know which elements of the hierarchy need to be updated/adjusted as the for loop cycles.

reference.df <- data.frame(i = c(rep(1, 9), rep(2, 9), rep(3, 9)), j = c(rep(c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3),3)), k = c(rep(c(1, 2, 3),9)))
```

### Code to run function:

```
reg.obj <- i.data[[reference.df$i[[i]]]][[reference.df$j[[i]]]][[reference.df$k[[i]]]] 

for(i in seq_along(reference.df$k)){
  
  add.points()
  
}
```

Remember: I am unable to run anything after the function within the for loop because R will interpret the next line as the user input being fed to `readlines()`. Thus, the whole point of this loop and function - getting user input, saving, and cycling to the next image for the user to provide input on - will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who runs into an issue like this. Don't be stupid like me. Use the `return()` function within your function to convert your variable into an output that you can feed into your nested list thusly:
in the function:

```
myfun(){
#do stuff to make object containing update
return(update.obj)
}

#run the function:

list[[x]][[y]][[z]] <- myfun()

#is equivalent to below occurring outside a function:
list[[x]][[y]][[z]] <- update.obj
```

Yes this was stupid but hopefully I helped someone avoid my fundamental mistake here. If you can avoid it, don't use `assign()` in a function.